# Price not showing when creating a custom product in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product

I am tring to create a new product but I do not get the price enabled on the admin panel.

I create a product_types.xml with this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="my_product" label="My Product" modelInstance="My\Module\Model\Product\Type\MyProduct" composite="false" isQty="true" canUseQtyDecimals="false" indexPriority="30" sortOrder="20">
        <customAttributes>
            <attribute name="is_real_product" value="false"/>
            <attribute name="refundable" value="true"/>
        </customAttributes>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then I create the model as `My\Module\Model\Product\Type\MyProduct` like this:

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Model\Product\Type;

use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Virtual;

class MyProduct extends Virtual
{
    /**
     * Product type code
     */
    const TYPE_CODE = 'my_product';
}
```

When I try to create a new product in the admin panel I do not get the option to input a price. What Am I missing? By the way I have tested this model with AbstractType and Simple Product too.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I found what was missing. You need to set price and other attributes to any new prodcut_type. You add so by adding this to your InstallData.php file:

```
  if (version_compare($version, '0.0.3', '<')) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $fieldList = [
            'price',
            'special_price',
            'special_from_date',
            'special_to_date',
            'minimal_price',
            'cost',
            'tier_price',
        ];

        // make these attributes applicable to downloadable products
        foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
            $applyTo = explode(
                ',',
                $eavSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $field, 'apply_to')
            );
            if (!in_array('my_product', $applyTo)) {
                $applyTo[] = 'my_product';
                $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    $field,
                    'apply_to',
                    implode(',', $applyTo)
                );
            }
        }
    }
```